# Magento 2 - add Enable / Disable field for custom module

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, module, extensions

I want to add some fields in the Magento 2 Admin Panel for my custom module and then I want to check in the phtml file if this field is have value or not.

I need to add this fields:

```
- enable / disable (yes/no field type) ;
- Add text {input text field type};
- upload image;
```

the upload image field must have the option to delete the image too.

For enable / disable I add this in the system.xml:

```
  <section id="mymodule" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <class>separator-top</class>
        <label>Module</label>
        <tab>mymodule</tab>
        <resource>Module_First::mymodule_configuration</resource>
        <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
            <label>General Configuration</label>
            <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Enable</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
```

I want to know what is the format for `adminhtml/system.xml` and how I can check this fields value in the phtml file (or what is the best way to check the value for this fields).

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add below code into each of your controller at first line of execute method:

```
if (!$this->moduleEnabled()) {
    return $this->_forwardNoroute();
}
```

**moduleEnabled()**:

```
/**
 * Retrieve true if extension is enabled.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
protected function moduleEnabled()
{
    return (bool) $this->getConfigValue(
        self::XML_PATH_EXTENSION_ENABLED,
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
}
```

**XML_PATH_EXTENSION_ENABLED contains path of system.xml  to enabled/disabled module**

```
/**
 * Extension enabled config path
 */
const XML_PATH_EXTENSION_ENABLED = '<Secton_Name>/general/enabled';
```

Answer (score 2):

To add enable/disable field in system.xml, you need to do this code in syste.xml file.

```
Vendor\Extension\etc\adminhtml\system.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
  <system>
    <section id="mymodule" sortOrder="150" type="text" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
      <label>Mymodule Label</label>
      <tab>mymoduletab</tab>
      <resource>Module_First::mymodule_configuration</resource>
      <group id="general" translate="label" sortOrder="10" type="text" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <label>General Configuration</label>
        <field id="enable" translate="label" sortOrder="10" type="select" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
          <label>Enable</label>
          <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
        </field>
      </group>
    </section>
  </system>
</config>
```

And to check that field value in phtml you can create Helper file (Data.php) at this location `Vendor/Extension/Helper/Data.php`.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $context;

    public function __construct(Context $context)
    {
        $this->context = $context;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function isEnable()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('mymodule/general/enable', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    }
}
```

Now Write this code in phtml file :

```
<?php 
$helper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Vendor\Extension\Helper\Data'); 
if($helper->isEnable()) : ?>

//WRITE YOUR CODE HERE

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer is work but how I can get the the input text value?

Comment: If above answer help you, accept it so it help other in community as well. 
And for input text value you need to create another function in helper and also change field name into that.

Comment: and for upload image field?

Comment: Any field you need to do the same things, create one function in Helper and and change field name into that.

Comment: can you create an example for the image upload field? and how I will get it in the phtml?

Comment: For file upload you need to check this : https://magecomp.com/blog/add-custom-file-upload-control-magento-2/

Comment: okay thanks is not help me very much the last url but is okay

Comment: I created a **toggle button yes/no** but unable to bind function of the module with this button  can you please  refer this link  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296371/magento2-how-to-create-toggle-button-yes-no-in-admin-side?noredirect=1#comment427071_296371

Answer (score 0):

Try this to check if your module is enable in system configuration

**In your Block**

```
protected $scopeConfig;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    ...
)
{
    ...
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    ...
}

public function getConfigValue($section_group_field)
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        $section_group_field,
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
}
```

**In your phtml file**

```
if($block->getConfigValue("mymodule/general/enable")){
    // your code
}
```