# Magento 2 save guest order to specific customer

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, customer, guest-checkout

I am trying to assign a guest order to a specific customer programmatically.

I have loaded the collection of orders placed by the guest users using following code:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory    $orderCollectionFactory,
) {
    $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
}

public function getGuestOrderCollection()
{
    $orderCollecion = $this->orderCollectionFactory
        ->create()
        ->addFieldToSelect('*');

    $orderCollecion->addAttributeToFilter('customer_is_guest', ['eq'=>1]);
    foreach($orderCollecion as $orderData){
        if($orderData->getCustomerId()){
            $order->setCustomerId($orderData->getCustomerId());
            $order->setCustomerIsGuest(0);
            $this->orderRepository->save($orderData);
            $message = "DONE";
        } else {
            $message = "Fail";
        }
    }
    return $message;
}
```

It doesn't work. It's not saving the order to that customer.

Not getting any error though.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Nisse i8t would be better if you can answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your code doesn't make a lot of sense to me. An order that was saved as a guest order should not have a customer_id set. Is your code passing into the `if($orderData->getCustomerId())` block at all?

Also, do note that your returned `$message` variable will currently only be set for the last order in the collection.

That said, it looks like you are trying to save `$order`, while you should actually be using `$orderData`, like so:

```
public function __construct(
  \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
) {
  $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
}

public function getGuestOrderCollection() {

  $orderCollecion = $this->orderCollectionFactory
    ->create()
    ->addFieldToSelect('*');

  $orderCollecion->addAttributeToFilter('customer_is_guest', ['eq'=>1]);
  foreach($orderCollecion as $orderData){

    if($orderData->getCustomerId()) {
      $orderData->setCustomerId($orderData->getCustomerId());
      $orderData->setCustomerIsGuest(0);
      $orderData->save($orderData);
      $message = "DONE";
    } else{  
      $message = "Fail";
    }

  return $message;
}
```

Comment: Hi,  you can say i want to update the customer email field in order.   Is there any way to do this?  will it work with cron?  I am trying this in cron.

Comment: You can update the customer email field with $orderData->setCustomerEmail('yourcustomeremail@example.com');

Comment: Yes thanks working.  Is it possible to manage cron  through configuration?  i mean if module is disable then our cron also stay disabled?

Comment: Only if you disable the module entirely through app/etc/config.php. Otherwise you could opt for creating a custom setting with enable/disable in your module. See this question for an example: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203535/magento-2-add-enable-disable-field-for-custom-module