# Enable Module in magento2?

Tags: magento2.2

How to enable /disble module in admin configuration setting .....

I also refer [Magento 2 - add Enable / Disable field for custom module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203535/magento-2-add-enable-disable-field-for-custom-module.But) how to enable/disable full module

Thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the field Enable/Disable in the System config and use the value entered there.
Check the below example of system config file. It should always be named as `system.xml` and put inside the `<Module>/etc/adminhtml` directory.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="helloworld" translate="label" sortOrder="100">
            <!-- add a new tab with id helloworld -->
            <label>Hello World</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="helloworld" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <!-- add a new section with id helloworld and for tab helloworld -->
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Hello World Configuration</label>
            <tab>helloworld</tab>
            <resource>Excellence_First::test_config</resource>
            <group id="active_display" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <!-- add a new group with id active display -->
                <label>Hello World Configuration Options</label>
                <field id="scope" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <!-- add a new field with id scope -->
                    <label>Enable Helloworld Controller</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Once you successfully implement the above file you will see the output in the `Stores > Configurations` page.
Under the Tab titled "Hello World" you will see the Section "Hello World Configuration", by clicking on it, you will be sent to the configurations page of the module.

Which will have the Dropdown containing Yes and No options. select one of them and the option will be saved in the `core_config_data` table in the database.

To get the value in the block or helper or model or Controller or any where, you need to add dependency in the respective class's constructor.

```
\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
```

and assign it to the member variable of the class.

To get the value, you can use `$this->scopeConfig->getValue('path/to/field');`

For further reference you can use the following links.
http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2016/04/10/magento2-system-xml/
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/87835/16246

Comment: i will do it.....

Comment: how to disable ko template

Comment: To disable the ko template, you need to pass the data in the JS using some kind of options in json.

Comment: please post some more info on what you need to achieve so i can guide you more.

Comment: @thanks .... i have do it.....How to disable admin grid column

Comment: any idea ......