# How to enable/disable Custom Module in magento2

Tags: magento2

Hi am new to magento 2 and learning how to to create custom modules and i have added a option to enable disable from drop down and also added a config file but that seems to be not working. can anyone help me out.

am sharing my code:-

**CONFIG.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Store/etc/config.xsd">
 <default>
     <custom_module>
       <general>
           <enable>0</enable>
              <title>Custom Customer Attribute</title>
         </general>
     </custom_module>
 </default>
</config>
```

**SYESTEM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Config/etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
    <tab id="mytab" translate="label" sortOrder="200">
        <label>Eecom</label>
    </tab>

    <section id="custom_module" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="300" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <class>separator-top</class>
        <label>Custom Customer Attribute</label>
        <tab>mytab</tab>
        <resource>Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute::config_custom_module</resource>
        <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>General Configuration</label>
            <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Enable Module</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field> 
        </group>
  </section>
</system>
</config>
```

**Helper/Data.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Eecom . All rights reserved.
 */
namespace Eecom\CustomCustomerAttribute\Helper;
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function isEnabled()
{
    return (boolean) $this->getConfig('eecom_customcustomerattribute/general/enable');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Vendor\Extension\etc\adminhtml\system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
  <system>
    <section id="mymodule" sortOrder="150" type="text" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
      <label>Mymodule Label</label>
      <tab>mymoduletab</tab>
      <resource>Module_First::mymodule_configuration</resource>
      <group id="general" translate="label" sortOrder="10" type="text" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <label>General Configuration</label>
        <field id="enable" translate="label" sortOrder="10" type="select" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
          <label>Enable</label>
          <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
        </field>
      </group>
    </section>
  </system>
</config>
```

And to check that field value in phtml you can create Helper file (`Data.php`) at this location `Vendor/Extension/Helper/Data.php`.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $context;

    public function __construct(Context $context)
    {
        $this->context = $context;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function isEnable()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('mymodule/general/enable', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    }
}
```

Now Write this code in phtml file :

```
<?php 
$helper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Vendor\Extension\Helper\Data'); 
if($helper->isEnable()) : ?>

//WRITE YOUR CODE HERE

<?php endif; ?>
```

And more refer this link :-

**[Magento 2 - add Enable / Disable field for custom module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203535/magento-2-add-enable-disable-field-for-custom-module)**

may be help this code ..

Answer (score 0):

**system.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="mytab" translate="custom Configuration" sortOrder="100" class="trademe-extensions-tab">
            <label>Custom Customer Attribute</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="custom_module" translate="TradeMe Settings" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Custom Customer Attribute</label>
            <tab>mytab</tab>
            <resource>Eecom_CustomCustomerAttribute::custom_module</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="TradeMe Configuration" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable Module</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field> 
        </group>
  </section>
</system>
</config>
```

**Controller file**

```
protected $scopeConfig;

const CUSTOM_MODULE_ENABLE = 'custom_module/general/enable';

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
) {
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
}

public function execute()
{
    echo $isEnable  = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::CUSTOM_MODULE_ENABLE, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
}
```

Comment: inside adminhtml directory??

Comment: You can add any Action, Block and Helper File.

Comment: i have already tried this but it didint work check my helper code

Comment: You can add my code in the helper file and try it.

Answer (score 0):

Your Helper File replace by this code

```
<?php

namespace Eecom\CustomCustomerAttribute\Helper;

use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

    const MODULE_ENABLE_DISABLE = 'custom_module/general/enable'; // SectionName/GroupName/FieldNAme from system.xml

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function setStoreScope()
    {
        return ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
    }
    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(static::MODULE_ENABLE_DISABLE, $this->setStoreScope());
    }
}
```

> **Note: module is not directly enable or disable from system.xml to field. we are provide admin can easily interact with our module our module provide more flexibility using system.xml**

For Understanding system.xml [click here](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-system-xml-configuration-magento-2.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to disable the module via terminal

`bin/magento module:disable ${MODULE_NAME}`

If it says there is no such module, try listing all enabled ones to find yours

`bin/magento module:status --enabled`

Reference to [official dosc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-enable.html)